# Android Fragment problems (converting my app)

Tags: android, list, dialog, android-alertdialog, fragment

I am currently converting my app over to Fragments, and have run into a number of problems. I hope to be able to solve them all with your help, and will edit my post once I have solved a certain part of the conversion.

**First problem:**
AlertDialogs. When the user clicks on a button, maybe later a ListView item, they are presented with an AlertDialog to choose the account they want to see. I do this for Facebook and Twitter. However, the double construction confuses me, and ListDialog seems to load its content differently.

So, my code for the Activity:

```
package bas.sie.Antonius;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;

import com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockFragment;

public class External extends SherlockFragment implements OnClickListener {

    Button mBtnOuderPortaal;
    Button mBtnTeletop;
    Button mBtnWebmail;
    Button mBtnInfobord;
    Button mBtnTwitter;
    Button mBtnFacebook;
    Button mBtnYouTube;
    String URLhome;
    String Title;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        mBtnOuderPortaal = (Button) getActivity().findViewById(
                R.id.btnOuderPortaal);
        mBtnOuderPortaal.setOnClickListener(this);
        mBtnTeletop = (Button) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.btnTeletop);
        mBtnTeletop.setOnClickListener(this);
        mBtnWebmail = (Button) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.btnWebmail);
        mBtnWebmail.setOnClickListener(this);
        mBtnInfobord = (Button) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.btnInfobord);
        mBtnInfobord.setOnClickListener(this);
        mBtnTwitter = (Button) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.btnTwitter);
        mBtnTwitter.setOnClickListener(this);
        mBtnFacebook = (Button) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.btnFacebook);
        mBtnFacebook.setOnClickListener(this);
        mBtnYouTube = (Button) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.btnYouTube);
        mBtnYouTube.setOnClickListener(this);

    }

    void showDialog() {
        DialogFragment newFragment = MyAlertDialogFragment
                .newInstance(R.string.twitter_dialog_title);
        newFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "dialog");
    }

    void showFBDialog() {
        DialogFragment newFragment = MyFBAlertDialogFragment
                .newInstance(R.string.facebook_dialog_title);
        newFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "dialog");
    }

    public static class MyFBAlertDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {

        String URLhome;
        String Title;
        final CharSequence[] Facebook = { "Spot Antoniuscollege",
                "ACG Mediagroep" };

        public static MyAlertDialogFragment newInstance(int title) {
            MyAlertDialogFragment frag = new MyAlertDialogFragment();
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putInt("Kies Facebook-account", title);
            frag.setArguments(args);
            return frag;
        }

        @Override
        public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            int title = getArguments().getInt("title");

            return new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
            .setTitle(title)
            .setItems(Facebook, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
                    switch (item) {
                    case 0:
                        URLhome = "http://m.facebook.com/spotcarmelcollege";
                        Title = "Facebook ACG Spot";

                        Intent i = new Intent();
                        i.setClass(getActivity(), MyWebView.class);
                        i.putExtra("home", URLhome);
                        i.putExtra("title", Title);
                        startActivityForResult(i, 0);
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        URLhome = "http://m.facebook.com/pages/ACG-Media/128125633969183";
                        Title = "Facebook ACG Media";

                        Intent i1 = new Intent();
                        i1.setClass(getActivity(), MyWebView.class);
                        i1.putExtra("home", URLhome);
                        i1.putExtra("title", Title);
                        startActivityForResult(i1, 0);
                    default:
                        return;
                    }
                }
                getDialog.create();
            )
        }

    }

        public static class MyAlertDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {

            final CharSequence[] Twitter = { "@ACGouda", "@Spot_ACG",
                    "@ACGmediatheek" };
            String URLhome;

            public static MyAlertDialogFragment newInstance(int title) {
                MyAlertDialogFragment frag = new MyAlertDialogFragment();
                Bundle args = new Bundle();
                args.putInt("title", title);
                frag.setArguments(args);
                return frag;
            }

            @Override
            public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                int title = getArguments().getInt("title");

                return new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
                .setTitle(title)
                s.setItems(Twitter,
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
                                switch (item) {
                                case 0:
                                    URLhome = "https://mobile.twitter.com/#!/ACGouda";

                                    Intent intent = new Intent(
                                            Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                                    intent.setData(Uri.parse(URLhome));
                                    startActivity(intent);
                                    break;
                                case 1:
                                    URLhome = "https://mobile.twitter.com/#!/Spot_ACG";

                                    Intent intent1 = new Intent(
                                            Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                                    intent1.setData(Uri.parse(URLhome));
                                    startActivity(intent1);
                                    break;
                                case 2:
                                    URLhome = "https://mobile.twitter.com/#!/ACGmediatheek";

                                    Intent intent2 = new Intent(
                                            Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                                    intent2.setData(Uri.parse(URLhome));
                                    startActivity(intent2);
                                    break;
                                default:
                                    return;
                                }
                            }
                        });
                AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
                alert.show();
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.btnFacebook:
                showFBDialog();
                break;
            case R.id.btnTwitter:
                showDialog();
                break;
            case R.id.btnInfobord:
                URLhome = "http://carmelcollegegouda.nl/site_ant/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=182&Itemid=131&lang=nl";
                Title = "Infobord";

                Intent bord = new Intent();
                bord.setClass(getActivity(), MyWebView.class);
                bord.putExtra("home", URLhome);
                bord.putExtra("title", Title);
                startActivityForResult(bord, 0);
                break;
            case R.id.btnOuderPortaal:
                URLhome = "https://portaal.mijnsom.nl/login/ccg";
                Title = "Onderwijsportaal";

                Intent portaal = new Intent();
                portaal.setClass(getActivity(), MyWebView.class);
                portaal.putExtra("home", URLhome);
                portaal.putExtra("title", Title);
                startActivityForResult(portaal, 0);
                break;
            case R.id.btnTeletop:
                URLhome = "http://antoniuscollege.teletop.nl/";

                Intent teletop = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                teletop.setData(Uri.parse(URLhome));
                startActivity(teletop);
                break;
            case R.id.btnMail:
                URLhome = "https://webmail.carmelcollegegouda.nl/";
                Title = "Webmail";

                Intent mail = new Intent();
                mail.setClass(getActivity(), MyWebView.class);
                mail.putExtra("home", URLhome);
                mail.putExtra("title", Title);
                startActivityForResult(mail, 0);
                break;
            case R.id.btnYouTube:
                URLhome = "http://m.youtube.com/results?search_query=Antoniuscollege&oq=Antoniuscollege&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&gs_l=youtube-psuggest.3...4430l12422l0l12750l31l31l9l1l2l0l122l1657l20j1l21l0.";

                Intent YT = new Intent();
                YT.setClass(getActivity(), MyWebView.class);
                YT.putExtra("home", URLhome);
                startActivityForResult(YT, 0);
                break;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

The errors are at:

-`.create();` on the first dialog, which says

`Syntax error on token "create", Identifier expected after this token`

`Syntax error, insert ";" to complete MethodDeclaration`

`Syntax error, insert ";" to complete ReturnStatement`

`Syntax error, insert ")" to complete MethodInvocation`

`Syntax error, insert "}" to complete ClassBody`

-`MyAlertDialogFragment` in the first `showDialog();`, saying that `MyAlertDialogFragment` cannot be resolved.

-In the initialization of the second Dialog:

`Syntax error on token ".", delete this token`

`The method setItems(CharSequence[], new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){}) is undefined for the type External.MyFBAlertDialogFragment.MyAlertDialogFragment`

`Type mismatch: cannot convert from AlertDialog.Builder to Dialog`

Then also on the `builder` from creating the second Dialog: `builder cannot be resolved`. This one is obviously legit, but I have no solution.

It's also complaining about the resource directory name being invalid.

The last problem I just fixed :).

I'm using ABS, but this is one of the tabs in ABS. This means it needs to be a Fragment, but not show the ActionBar.

Comment: You've just got syntax errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everyone for trying to help, but it's been solved for a while.

However, it is a lot of code to post here, so if anyone wants to know: shoot me a message and I will try to help as best I can!

Answer (score 0):

You've got multiple syntax errors. Thats what

> Identifier expected after this token

means

You should **move your Fragments into there own class files** that would be much easier to maintain.

I can spot one error *i think* but it's hard in a browser:

```
                default:
                    return;
                }
            }
            getDialog.create();
        )
    }
```

Should be:

```
                default:
                    return;
                }
            }
            getDialog.create();
        }
      );        
}
```

(Yes one semicolon missing)

Comment: What do you mean "moving the Fragments into their own class files?" Also, it didn't change anything, editing that part like you said...

Comment: Yeah it probably wouldn't change anything as you'll have even more syntax errors elsewhere!

Comment: Each class file you have i.e. `public class SomeClass {}` can be moved into it's own `SomeClass.java` file, then if one of your classes has compilation errors it won't affect the others.

Comment: OK, but won't that be more difficult? It surely won't help my syntax errors, and I would still need two classes for the two ListDialogs, no?

Anyhow, I think I'll do it once I get everything sorted with converting to Fragments :)

Comment: That'll make everything 10 x easier and more maintainable. The corner stone of OO programming.

Comment: I'll look into it. Do you think that can help me track down my problems? And how should I reference that class from this one?

Comment: Your problems are synctactial at the moment so yes. It depends you might not want to reference the class, but do some kind of message handling or pass the data you need in Intents or through constructors. Go away split your files, try and fix your errors and come back with new questions if you need to.

Answer (score 0):

You post your code for an **activity** but your convention is inherited from **SherlockFragment** not **SherlockFragmentActivity**.

You may should take a look at [Fragment](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html) vs [FragmentActivity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentActivity.html).

Comment: I've solved it already, someone helped me adopt the right way to do this. However, as this was outside of SO, I have not marked the right answer yet. I will take a look at the pages you mentioned, thank you!